# capture a variable content and pass it to a second view controller

Tags: objective-c

I have read so much on the subject of passing variable between ViewController in Xcode I am totally lost.

1:I have a members database on my server which is populated with members details

2: In xcode a have a "ViewController.h and .m" which run code allowing users to authenticate with the members data table on my sever. This works perfectly well, no issues.

What I want to do is capture the "login" and "password" into two variables and use the variables in a second "ViewController".

First ViewController.h:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {    

UITextField *txtUsername;
UITextField *txtPassword;    
} 

@property (nonatomic, retain)    IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender;
```

First ViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"


#import "SBJson.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize txtPassword, txtUsername;

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
@try {

    if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {




        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
       NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];


        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com/check1.php"];


        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);                    

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];

            NSLog(@"%d",success);


            if(success == 1)
            {

                //NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                //[self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

               WebViewController *second = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

                [self presentModalViewController:second  animated:YES];


            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
            }

        } else {
            if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
}
}
```

Second ViewController.h

```
@interface LettoWebViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIWebView *lettoWebView;

 NSString *AmemberUsername;
 NSString *AmemberPassword;
}

@property (retain) NSString *AmemberUsername;
@property (retain) NSString *AmemberPassword;
```

Second ViewController.m

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "SBJson.h"


@interface WebViewController ()

@end


@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize AmemberPassword, AmemberUsername;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[AmemberUsername text],[AmemberPassword text]];
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

NSURL *myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com/apps/index.php"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:myURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


[lettoWebView loadRequest:request];    


}
```

My questions is; how can I can I pass the two variables in the most simple way.

Any help would be great but please be kind I am very new to xcode and coding in general.

Regards

DJ

Comment: `WebViewController *second = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[second setAmemberUsername:[txtUsername text]]; [second set AmemberPassword:[txtPassword text]];
[self presentModalViewController:second  animated:YES];`

Comment: Hi rmaddy, many thanks for your fast reply. I have used your code but when I build the code I am getting an warning "NSSTring may not respond to 'text'". This is in the second ViewController where it says, "    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[AmemberUsername text],[AmemberPassword text]];" any ideas what may be causing this. The NSLog output is "-[NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e5a460'"

Comment: i rmaddy, There is a typo in my comments, it should read ""NSString may not respond to 'text'"'

Comment: It's because they are already NSString... so: `initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",AmemberUsername,AmemberPassword]`

Comment: Hi rmaddy, your a star. I have been working on this for hours. I have gained knowledge with your help. Again many thanks. DJ

Comment: You're welcome. But: I'm Larme, not rmaddy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
When you created `WebViewController`, you just had to set the two parameters.

```
WebViewController *second = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
[second setAmemberUsername:[txtUsername text]]; 
[second setAmemberPassword:[txtPassword text]]; 
[self presentModalViewController:second  animated:YES];
```

In your `viewDidLoad` of the `WebViewController`:
There was an issue, you wrote:

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[AmemberUsername text],[AmemberPassword text]];
```

But, `AmemberPassword` and `AmemberUserName` are `NSString`. So they don't know the `text` method. They aren's `UITextField`.

So the correction is:

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",AmemberUsername,AmemberPassword];
```